# error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to insert emp data into SqlServer DB from eclipse oxygen. I have successfully installed jdbc driver sqljdbc41 & Tomcat server 9 as well.

when i click on add data button then i am getting error, below is the code for DatabaseDemo.html & DataBase.java

DatabaseDemo.html:

```
<form method="post" action="./DataBase">
name    :   <input type="text" name ="txtname"/><br><br>
address :   <textarea name="txtadr" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea><br><br>
contact :   <input type="text" name="txtcnt"/><br><br>
age     :   <input type="text" name="txtage"/><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="add data"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="reset" value="clear"/>
</form>
```

DataBase.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.Statement;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DataBase
 */
@WebServlet("/DataBase")
public class DataBase extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Connection con;
    Statement stmt; 
    String name, address;
    int contact, age;
    String dbString="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost; databaseName=Emp; tableName=emp1;  integratedSecurity=true; user=sa; password=qwerty";

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

        try {
            name=request.getParameter("txtname");
            address=request.getParameter("txtadr");
            contact=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtcnt"));
            age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txtage"));

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(dbString, "sa", "siva123");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query="insert into emp1 values('"+name+"','"+address+"',"+contact+","+age+");";
            stmt.execute(query);
            System.out.println("Data Inserted Succesfully");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            System.out.println("Data not Inserted");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Note: I am new for programming so can any one help me pls

Comment: Have you deployed the driver to your application server, or included it in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application? You likely haven't, so the driver can't be found out run time. Also, in general, you shouldn't be using `DriverManager` from a web application: use a data source (preferably backed by a connection pool).